# Query Returning Too Many Results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I am trying to get the largest population of any city in each country in a query. I need to join the city and country tables, as they are located on two tables, and join them through the country code.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT country.name         AS country, 
       city.name            AS city, 
       Max(city.population) AS max_pop 
FROM   country 
       INNER JOIN city 
               ON( country.country_code = city.country_code ) 
GROUP  BY country.name, 
          city.name 
ORDER  BY country.name ASC;
```

My thought process was to get my country name, city name, and max from the joined table. I assumed and have tested, that max will give me only one result, however in this case its giving me several! I have both city and country name in my group by in order to get it to run.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT co.name         AS country,
       ct.name         AS city, 
       t.pop AS max_pop 
FROM country AS co
      INNER JOIN (
               SELECT country_code, Max(population) AS pop FROM city GROUP BY country_code
             ) t ON co.country_code = t.country_code 
      INNER JOIN city AS ct ON ct.population = t.pop AND co.country_code = ct.country_code 
ORDER  BY country.name ASC;
```

Comment: you have no city.name in nested query

Comment: i dont mean in the group by predicate (that's correct) but you select it in the outer query but its not among the columns after the join

Comment: This can be much simpler. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Much* shorter and faster with [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) (PostgreSQL extension to the SQL standard):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       co.name       AS country
      ,ci.name       AS city
      ,ci.population AS max_pop
       -- add more columns as you please
FROM   country co
JOIN   city    ci USING (country_code)
ORDER  BY 1, 3 DESC, 2;
```

If two cities have the equally largest population in one country, I pick the alphabetically first in this case. That's why I added the *positional parameter 2* (for `ci.name`) to the `ORDER BY` clause.

I also simplified with table aliases and a `USING` equi-join.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Oh, I don't know postgreSQL enough, I didn't know DISTINCT ON existed. Thank you for sharing.